# How to set a proxy in Firebase GetAccessToken?

Tags: firebase, proxy, firebase-notifications

tI need to set a proxy server and port in my c# procedure while using Google APIs in my token request (push notification service).
Or rather I think I need it, because in this method

```
private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        string retVal = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            string sPathFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FCMkeyFullPath"];
            using (var stream = new FileStream(sPathFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {                
                var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging");                
                retVal = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);   // <-- EXCEPTION HERE             
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = ex.Message;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

I get this Exception:

> An error occurred while sending the request.

Surfing the web I found the class

```
public class ProxySupportedHttpClientFactory : HttpClientFactory
{
    protected override HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
    {
        //ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential("user1", "user1");
        //var proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:3128", true, null, credentials);
        var proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:3128", true, null, null);        
        var webRequestHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseProxy = true,
            Proxy = proxy,
            UseCookies = false
        };
        return webRequestHandler;
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I added to my C# web app solution a **MyProxyAssembly** project with only one class as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProxyAssembly.dll
{
    public class MyProxy : IWebProxy
    {
        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get { return new NetworkCredential("user", "password"); }
            //or get { return new NetworkCredential("user", "password","domain"); }
            set { }
        }

        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {            
            return new Uri("http://myproxy:8080");
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This project's output is a DLL library and I included it in my solution dependencies and web project references. Then I added in my web.config these lines:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <module type = "MyProxyAssembly.dll.MyProxy, MyProxyAssembly" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

In this way I set my web app to use proxy credentials written in my code. It worked properly.